# LOG4J - Avoid same message two times in log

Tags: java, log4j

Here is my `log4j.properties` file

```
# Set loggers' levels
log4j.rootLogger=warn, trace_file

# Appender
log4j.appender.trace_file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.trace_file.Append=true
log4j.appender.trace_file.File=log/myLog.log
log4j.appender.trace_file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.trace_file.MaxBackupIndex=50

# PatternLayout
log4j.appender.trace_file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.trace_file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%p] (%F:%L) %m%n

# Classes
log4j.logger.my_package=info, trace_file
```

What I want :

- Store log requests from `my.package` in `trace_file` with at least `INFO` level
- Store log requests from all other loggers in `trace_file` ONLY if it's at least `WARN` level

My configuration does'nt work. If `my.package` raises a log request of level `WARN`, this log request gets written two times. If I use two separate appenders, there is no problem.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try removing the "trace_file" directive from the my_package logger statement.

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
log4j.logger.my_package=info, trace_file
```

to

```
log4j.logger.my_package=info
```

Appenders are inherited from the parent logger by default, so by specifying `trace_file` for both root logger and the `my_package`, you're telling it to do it twice.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Gevorg. It may be an additivity issue.

**Those who are using log4j.properties file :**

Add `log4j.additivity.com.example.package=false` .(replace org.hibernate with whatever package you need)

**Those who are using log4j.xml based config :**

```
<logger name="com.example.package" additivity="false">
....
</logger>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the role of the `rootLogger`.

A warning from  `my_package` with be caught by `trace_file` via the root logguer  `log4j.rootLogger=warn, trace_file`, and then by the same appender via the `log4j.logger.my_package=info, trace_file`

I suppose that when you created a second appender, you didn't specify it to the `rootLogger`, did you?

Alternatively, you can change only the level inherited from root and keep the same appender

```
log4j.logger.my_package=info
```

Answer (score 1):

Prevent appender-additivity through:

log4j.additivity.my_package=false

See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html, section "Appenders and Layouts"..

Quote:

> Appender Additivity
> The output of a log statement of logger C will go to all the appenders in C and its
> ancestors. This is the meaning of the term "appender additivity".
>
> However, if an ancestor of logger C, say P, has the additivity flag set to false, then
> C's output will be directed to all the appenders in C and its ancestors upto and
> including P but not the appenders in any of the ancestors of P.
>
> Loggers have their additivity flag set to true by default.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an additivity issue.

I'm not familiar with the property file configuration, but there should be an `additivity` flag option when you define a logger. Setting that to `false` should solve the issue. Also, by using the xml configuration instead you might leverage log4j's `Filter` option that is not available in the property file.

It should be something like this: `log4j.logger.my_package.additivity = false`

Finally, take a look at [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) if you never heard about it before